# CSS Conformance Tool

Tags: javascript, html, css

I remember there's a javascript project that you can include on a page that applies CSS classes depending on the browsers HTML conformance.  Much more fine grained than the usual "if IE" thing.  The only problem is, I can't remember the name of it... can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/docs) is what you are looking for?